# Does Macport's clang 3.7 have OpenMP support?

Tags: macos, clang, openmp, macports

Here it says that clang supports OpenMP since a few months:
http://blog.llvm.org/2015/05/openmp-support_22.html

Thus I installed clang-3.7 @3.7-r239386 on Mac OS X with Macports, which should correspond to the dev version of clang.

But it looks like it doesn't support OpenMP:

```
$ port contents clang-3.7 | grep omp.h  # nothing found
```

Does someone know why that clang doesn't support OpenMP and if it will soon?

Comment: For older version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159225/openmp-support-in-xcode-6-clang-3-5/26296137#26296137 , see comment by  Alexey Bataev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a libomp port now. See the notes (port notes libomp) for usage requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will also need to install the openmp library and use the compiler as instructed in the blog you linked.

Comment: Can the OpenMP library be installed via Macports? If no, is it worth filing a feature request for this in the Macports issue tracker? Or is this impossible for some legal or technical reason?

Comment: There is currently no port available.  You would need to build it yourself (should be rather easy).  If you want to throw together a Portfile to build it, please do file a ticket with the Portfile attached to request it be added to the repo.

Comment: I don't have the time or skills to put this Portfile together. I've marked your answer as accepted, although it would be more clear if you explicitly said that the openmp library can't be installed via Macports at this point in time. Thanks, Jeremy!

Comment: How has this matter progressed over the last 5 years?