# clang-omp in Xcode under El Capitan

Tags: c++, openmp, xcode7

I like to use openmp in a c++ project using Xcode as IDE. Unfortunately, Apple's Clang compiler does not support openmp ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159225/openmp-support-in-xcode-6-clang-3-5)), so I installed [clang-omp](https://clang-omp.github.io). I exactly followed the instructions given on that website to use it within Xcode, but I get the error message `can't exec '/usr/local/bin/clang++-omp' (No such file or directory)`. I tried to compile the simple example given on their website via terminal and I got it to work when I compile it via `clang-omp++ -fopenmp file.cpp`. For me it looks like Xcode should search for `/usr/local/bin/clang-omp++` (which exists in contrast to `/usr/local/bin/clang++-omp`). After making a symlink as suggested in the comments I get another error message: `library not found for -liomp5`. How can I fix this?

Comment: what about making a symbolic link? `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/clang-omp++ /usr/local/bin/clang++-omp`

Comment: @Gilles Nice idea, but I still get the error message although the file now exists...

Comment: I just noticed that there seems to be another error: library not found for -liomp5. I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case anyone else is trying to get clang-omp under Xcode to work, the correct way is (following the [official instructions](https://clang-omp.github.io)):

1. Install clang-omp using homebrew: `brew install clang-omp`
2. Create a new Xcode project
3. Add a new user-defined setting CC with the value `/usr/local/bin/clang-omp` under the project's build settings
4. Add `-fopenmp` to Other C Flags under the project's build settings
5. Add `/usr/local/include` to Header Search Paths under the project's build settings
6. Add `/usr/local/lib` to Library Search Paths under the project's build settings
7. Set Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) to `No` under the project's build settings
8. Add `/usr/local/lib/libiomp5.dylib` to Link Binary With Libraries under the project's build phases
9. Make a symbolic link via `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/clang-omp++ /usr/local/bin/clang++-omp` using the terminal
10. Use `#include <libiomp/omp.h>` to be able to use openmp in your project

Comment: @JosephK I know it's a little late, but try running `brew update` before `brew install`.

Comment: **Note (July 2016)**: `clang-omp` has been "[removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/c57e307)" from brew, OpenMP now being directly supported by upstream LLVM (available on brew as well). Regarding Xcode integration now, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: I've installed llvm38 from homebrew and while `-fopenmp` flag now correctly gets recognizer, I get a compile error stating that `omp.h` does not exists. I searched for the file and it really does not exist. What to do now?

Comment: If you install clang-3.8 and above from MacPorts, -fopenmp "just works."

Comment: To use in Xcode from MacPorts and then, similar to above:
[1] `sudo port install clang-3.8 ld64 +ld64_xcode`
[2] User-defined setting CC `/opt/local/bin/clang-mp/3.8`
[3] Other C Flags: `-fopenmp`
[4] Other Linker Flags: `-fopenmp`
[5] Enable Modules (C and Objective-C): `No`

[6] And done. The include and library search paths and linking requirements are baked into clang-mp-3.8. You will need `#include <omp.h>` as always.

(Inspired by Jan-Michael Tressler's openmp-dev post.)

Comment: What about newer `XCode`? Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

OpemMP runtimes are usually not delivered with clang, you can download and install from: https://www.openmprtl.org

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.