# Change compiler to clang-omp++ in xcode

Tags: clang, openmp, xcode7, clang++

I'm trying to follow the instructions on [OpenMP®/Clang](https://clang-omp.github.io/#try-openmp-clang) to enable openmp in Xcode. But `Add a new user-defined setting CC with the value /usr/local/bin/clang-omp` confuses me. I tried to change the Build Settings->Build Options-> Compilers for C/C++/Objective-C to /usr/local/bin/clang-omp++, but I got `Unsupported Compiler` error.

Please help, thanks ahead.

Comment: I think this SO could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668323/clang-omp-in-xcode-under-el-capitan

Comment: Follow this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380459/is-openmp-available-in-high-sierra-llvm/47230419#47230419

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set some user build settings to choose your compiler. You can set special build settings from the command line using the following syntax.

```
xcodebuild build FOO=bla
```

> Disclaimer: some of those build settings are undocumented (afaik). Use
>   at your own risk.
>
> Here are a few build settings that I found useful to inject C flags:
>
> - OTHER_CFLAGS
> - OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS
>
> or to replace the compiler(s) and linker(s):
>
> - CC
> - CPLUSPLUS
> - LD
> - LDPLUSPLUS
> - LIBTOOL
>
> The same approach works to control the "analyze" action:
>
> - CLANG_ANALYZER_EXEC
> - CLANG_ANALYZER_OTHER_FLAGS

[Sourced from cfe-dev mailing list](https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2014-March/035816.html)