# OpenMP multi-threading not working for Eigen library

Tags: c++, multithreading, matrix, openmp, eigen

Since my research involves doing large matrix products I am trying to enable OpenMP multi-threading capabilities for Eigen. Unfortunately I haven't had any luck so far.

I use Xcode 7 with the following compiler: `gcc --version`

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

After that I have configured the number of OpenMP threads I want to use, by setting `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4`. Then I compile my program using the following flags: `-O3 -fopenmp=libomp -DNDEBUG`. However trying to set or print the number of threads used by Eigen always returns `1`. So it looks like only one thread is used:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
...
Eigen::initParallel();
Eigen::setNbThreads(4);
int nthreads = Eigen::nbThreads( );
std::cout << "THREADS = " << nthreads <<std::ends; // returns '1'
```

Anyone has any idea why Eigen is only using one thread? According to the steps on the Eigen website (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html) this should work...?

Comment: Are you sure that your OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable is actually being passed as a preprocessor definition?  I'm not sure if all environment variables are treated as such when using gcc.

Comment: Never mind -- just saw that the env variable in question is checked at runtime, as specified in the Eigen multithreading docs.

Comment: Your compiler does not implement OpenMP.

Comment: Are you sure my compiler does not support OpenMP? Since I am using all the latest OSX software (El Capitan, Xcode 7), I would think OpenMP is supported since it is listed here as supported compiler on the [official website](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-compilers/). If you are right and OpenMP is not supported by my compiler. What would your advise be?

Comment: @verified.human Try it. Add a parallel section with that prints the thread number:
`#pragma omp parallel
 {
 printf("Hello World from thread = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
}`
Just make sure that you add a line break after the `pragma` line (I can't do that in comments).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668323/clang-omp-in-xcode-under-el-capitan/33687414

Comment: @verified.human This website is listing clang 3.7, but not Apple's clang 7.0.x

Comment: @verified.human, Did you solve ti? Thank You.