# Cython's prange not improving performance

Tags: python, numpy, openmp, cython, gil

I'm trying to improve the performance of some metric computations with Cython's `prange`. Here are my codes:

```
def shausdorff(float64_t[:,::1] XA not None, float64_t[:,:,::1] XB not None):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i
        Py_ssize_t n  = XB.shape[2]
        float64_t[::1] hdist = np.zeros(n)

    #arrangement to fix contiguity
    XB = np.asanyarray([np.ascontiguousarray(XB[:,:,i]) for i in range(n)])

    for i in range(n):
        hdist[i] = _hausdorff(XA, XB[i])
    return hdist

def phausdorff(float64_t[:,::1] XA not None, float64_t[:,:,::1] XB not None):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i
        Py_ssize_t n  = XB.shape[2]
        float64_t[::1] hdist = np.zeros(n)

    #arrangement to fix contiguity (EDITED)
    cdef float64_t[:,:,::1] XC = np.asanyarray([np.ascontiguousarray(XB[:,:,i]) for i in range(n)])

    with nogil, parallel(num_threads=4):
        for i in prange(n, schedule='static', chunksize=1):
            hdist[i] = _hausdorff(XA, XC[i])
    return hdist
```

Basically, in each iteration the hausdorff metric is computed between `XA` and each `XB[i]`. Here is the signature of the `_hausdorff` function:

```
cdef inline float64_t _hausdorff(float64_t[:,::1] XA, float64_t[:,::1] XB) nogil:
    ...
```

my problem is that both the sequential `shausdorff` and the parallel `phausdorff` have the same timings. Furthermore, it seems that `phausdorff` is not creating any thread at all.

So my question is what is wrong with my code, and how can I fix it to get threading working.

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
    Extension("custom_metric",
              ["custom_metric.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"],
              extra_compile_args = ["-O3", "-ffast-math", "-march=native", "-fopenmp" ],
              extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']
              ) 
]

setup( 
  name = "custom_metric",
  cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

**EDIT 1:** Here is a link to the html generated by `cython -a`: [custom_metric.html](http://csrg.cl/~mavillan/custom_metric.html)

**EDIT 2:** Here is an example on how to call the corresponding functions (you need to compile [the Cython file](http://csrg.cl/~mavillan/custom_metric.pyx) first)

```
import custom_metric as cm
import numpy as np

XA = np.random.random((9000, 210))
XB = np.random.random((1000, 210, 9))

#timing 'parallel' version
%timeit cm.phausdorff(XA, XB)

#timing sequential version
%timeit cm.shausdorff(XA, XB)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the equivalent to `omp_get_thread_num()` within the loop-body of the `prange`. See http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html

Comment: Could be that `XB` is a Python object? Run `cython -a custom_metric.pyx` with annotation.

Comment: Is there any change if `phausdorff` is decorated with `@cython.boundscheck(False)` and `@cython.wraparound(False)`?

Comment: @cgohlke I have changed that, explicity defining it as a memory view and theres is no change. @J.J. Hakala the macros `#cython: boundscheck=False` and `#cython: wraparound=False` are included at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Harald when I try to run that, Cython says: `Converting to Python object not allowed without gil`

Comment: @mavillan Are you using OSX? Since the information I can see on the internet suggests that the version of clang they supply doesn't support OpenMP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668323/clang-omp-in-xcode-under-el-capitan possibly, but I'm not using OSX myself so can't confirm...

Comment: @DavidW no, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Anaconda environment.

Comment: @mavillan, can you provide a small example on how to call `shausdorff` and `phausdorff` ?

Comment: @Harald I've added an example on how to use the functions.

Comment: Have you considered using a greater `chunk_size`?  Depending on the algorithm you can have a very poor data locality using a `chunk_size` of `1`.

Answer (score 4):

I think this the parallelization is working, but the extra overhead of the parallelization is eating up the time it would have saved. If I try with different sized arrays then I do begin to see a speed up in the parallel version

```
XA = np.random.random((900, 2100))
XB = np.random.random((100, 2100, 90))
```

Here the parallel version takes ~2/3 of the time of the serial version for me, which certainly isn't the 1/4 you'd expect, but does at least show some benefit.

---

One improvement I can offer is to replace the code that fixes contiguity:

```
XB = np.asanyarray([np.ascontiguousarray(XB[:,:,i]) for i in range(n)])
```

with

```
XB = np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(XB,[2,0,1]))
```

This speeds up both the parallel and non-parallel functions fairly significantly (a factor of 2 with the arrays you originally gave). It does make it slightly more obvious that you're being slowed down by overhead in the `prange` - the serial version is actually faster for the arrays in your example.

Comment: (Posted as community wiki since this doesn't present a solution so I wanted to remove it from contention for the bounty)