# What compiler can I use to install torch which supports OpenMP and nvcc on OS X 10.12?

Tags: macos, clang, openmp, torch, llvm-clang

I am attempting to install Torch (with CUDA support) on a MacBook Pro with an NVIDIA GeForce graphics card running OS X 10.12 by following the [installation instructions](http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html).

I'm using CUDA 8.0. Although the [CUDA system requirements](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#axzz4aD2Iui1S) do not list OS X 10.12 and Apple LLVM 8 as supported, the [CUDA download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) has a link for downloading OS X 10.12 and Apple LLVM 8 compatible CUDA.

The default settings of the torch install script specifies the clang compiler, and finds

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
```

It runs through several installation tasks without problems but then repeatedly tries and fails to find OpenMP

```
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp=libomp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [ ]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Failed
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
... (attempt with many other flags) ...
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing:  OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)
```

Quotes from the OpenMP website suggest that OpenMP is distributed with clang (more on that below). I couldn't find any authoritative sources about whether or not OpenMP is included with Apple LLVM as well. [Several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26296137/3303546) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980225/3303546) suggests that it is not, and that the two are incompatible. So I decided to play it safe and attempt to compile with llvm-clang instead.

### LLVM-Clang

[From the OpenMP website](http://openmp.llvm.org)

> With the release of Clang 3.8.0, OpenMP 3.1 support is enabled in
>   Clang by default, and the OpenMP runtime is therefore built as a
>   normal part of the Clang build, and distributed with the binary
>   distributions.

I used homebrew to install llvm and changed the following lines in the torch install script

```
# If we're on OS X, use clang
if [[ `uname` == "Darwin" ]]; then
    # make sure that we build with Clang. CUDA's compiler nvcc
    # does not play nice with any recent GCC version.
    export CC=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang
    export CXX=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++
fi
```

The correct compiler is found

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.9.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 3.9.1
```

But I still get the error

```
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing:  OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS)
```

Suggesting that either I have not correctly configured the compiler, or that my reading of the OpenMP website was incorrect.

Additionally, I assumed that because Apple LLVM is supported, other LLVM distributions would also be supported. However, the script throws an another error

```
nvcc fatal   : The version ('30901') of the host compiler ('clang') is not supported
```

Which suggests that I cannot use this compiler regardless of OpenMP support.

### GCC

Finally, I tried using a gcc compiler despite the warning in the torch install script, and it not being on the CUDA supported compilers list.

```
# If we're on OS X, use clang
if [[ `uname` == "Darwin" ]]; then
    # make sure that we build with Clang. CUDA's compiler nvcc
    # does not play nice with any recent GCC version.
    export CC=/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gcc-6
    export CXX=/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/g++-6
fi
```

The compiler is correctly discovered

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
```

And the OpenMP library is also correctly found

```
-- Try OpenMP C flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Try OpenMP CXX flag = [-fopenmp]
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED
-- Performing Test OpenMP_FLAG_DETECTED - Success
-- Found OpenMP: -fopenmp  
-- Compiling with OpenMP support
```

This shows that the torch install script is capable of detecting OpenMP if it is correctly configured with the compiler.

But as suggested by the comment, CUDA throws an error

```
nvcc fatal   : GNU C/C++ compiler is no longer supported as a host compiler on Mac OS X.
```

So I cannot simply solve my problem by using the gcc compiler.

### Question

**What compiler can I use to install torch which supports OpenMP and nvcc?**

If the answer is one of the compilers which I have already tried, how can I modify the install script or my compiler configuration to make it work?

Comment: I just went down a long rabbit hole returning to this question after a few weeks. Note to self: OpenMPI is *not* OpenMP.